# Wildfly Performance issues

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm having issues with my wildly installation. The version is 8.2.0. I observed that when number of connections gets to a certain level it would start rejecting connections. Here are my questions:

1. Is it only at worker under io subsystem that the thread configuration is set?
2. Are there other configurations in wildfly that I need to set that affect performance?
3. Is there a way I can know the number of threads currently been used so I can know when to adjust the configurations to accommodate additional load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is it only at worker under io subsystem that the thread configuration is set?

You can set a specific worker for your server in the undertow subsystem, then the thread pool settings are in the io subsystem as you mentionned.

> 2. Are there other configurations in wildfly that I need to set that affect performance?

Yes, there are a ton of them. Which are relevant is hard to say without any other element than "connections are 'rejected'". You should check error logs for your vhost at the very least.

> 3. Is there a way I can know the number of threads currently been used so I can know when to adjust the configurations to accommodate additional load?

Yes you can. Take a look at [this article](http://blog.akquinet.de/2014/09/15/monitoring-the-jboss-eap-wildfly-application-server-with-the-command-line-interface-cli/).

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the thread you referenced is for EJB. Do you have anyone on http?

I've checked my logs I can't seem to see anything on vhost. I'm running on Standalone, not domain where virtual hosts are created.

Comment: @Jibz On JBoss EAP 6.x you can have a look at the global threading state with the `/core-service=platform-mbean/type=threading:read-resource` CLI command ; the wildfly command must be the same or closely related. The thread-count attribute is probably the most relevant to your needs. I'll try to find something specific to the http connector.

Comment: @Jibz this article describes a way to monitor the undertow subsystem thread allocation on a per-deployment basis : http://blog.akquinet.de/2014/09/15/monitoring-the-jboss-eap-wildfly-application-server-with-the-command-line-interface-cli/ . I've updated the link in my answer to point out to this resource instead.